# Slick2D Will not load image even though it is there

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, lwjgl, freeze, slick2d

For some reason, my game will NOT freeze when the level starts, while the menu loads just fine!
The game will freeze when the boss music starts.
EDIT: Sorry, I found out that the screen froze because the canMove variables were stuck to false. But, the game will still randomly crash and say the image can not be found.

Here is my code:

This is the menu (Which works fine):

```
//Sprite sheeting
private SpriteSheet sleepSpriteSheet;
private Animation sleepAnimation;
private SpriteSheet walkSpriteSheet;
private Animation walkAnimation;

//System info
private String operatingSystem = Client.getOS();

//Game texuring
private static String IntroBackground = "res/images/level/IntroBackground.png";
private static String KnightQuestLogo = "res/images/icons/KnightQuestLogo.png";

//Menu Info
private static boolean readyForIntro = false;
private static boolean readyForPlay = false;
private static boolean showArrow = false;
private static String playButton = Button.PlayButton;
private static boolean playerSleeping = true;
private static boolean knightWalking = false;
private static float knightX = 145;
private static float knightY = 456;
private static float knightQuestLogoX = -750;
private static float knightQuestLogoY = 75;
private static boolean soundStarted = false;

public GameMenu(int State) {
}

// Render the game
@Override
public void render(GameContainer GameContainer, StateBasedGame SBG,
        Graphics G) throws SlickException {
    //Draw Background Image
    G.drawImage(new Image(IntroBackground), 0, 0);

    //Choose what animation to use
    if(playerSleeping) {
        sleepAnimation.draw(145, 406, 250, 250);
    }
    else {
        walkAnimation.draw(knightX, knightY, 175, 200);
    }

    //Draw Floor
    G.drawImage(new Image(Block.GroundTile), 0, 656);

    //Draw The Logo
    G.drawImage(new Image(KnightQuestLogo), knightQuestLogoX, knightQuestLogoY);

    //Draw the Play Button
    if(readyForPlay) {
        G.drawImage(new Image(playButton), 750, 315);
        if(showArrow) {
            G.drawImage(new Image(Icon.Arrow), 730, 335);
        }
    }

    //System Info
    G.drawString("Game State: " + this.getID(), 10, 30);
    G.drawString("X:" + Mouse.getX() + " Y:" + Mouse.getY(), 10, 50);
    G.drawString("Your OS: " + operatingSystem, 10, 70);
}

// Update the game
@Override
public void update(GameContainer GameContainer, StateBasedGame SBG,
        int Delta) throws SlickException {
    //Start Sound (Would be started in init(), But the StopSound function will not work if done so.
    if(!soundStarted) {
        PlaySound.playSound("res/sounds/startup/MainMenu.wav");
        soundStarted = true;
    }

    //When ready, slide the logo to the right
    if (readyForIntro) {
        if (knightQuestLogoX < 750.0) {
            knightQuestLogoX += Delta * .5f;
        }
    }

    //When ready, allow the player the press the play button
    if(readyForPlay) {
        if(Mouse.getX() > 755 && Mouse.getX() < 875 && Mouse.getY() > 345 && Mouse.getY() < 400) {
            showArrow = true;
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                playerSleeping = false;
                knightWalking = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            showArrow = false;
        }
    }

    //If the knight is walking in the intro, slide him off the screen
    if(knightWalking) {
        if(knightX < 1290) {
            knightX += Delta* .5f;
        }
        else {
            SBG.enterState(1, new FadeOutTransition(new Color(Color.black)), new FadeInTransition(new Color(Color.black)));
            PlaySound.stopSound();
            PlaySound.playSound("res/sounds/events/LeaveState.wav");
        }
    }
}

// Initialize the GameState
@Override
public void init(GameContainer GameContainer, StateBasedGame SBG)
        throws SlickException {
    //Start the thread for the Intro
    new Thread(new MenuIntro()).start();

    //Create the Sprite sheets
    sleepSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("res/images/characters/knight/spritesheets/SleepAnimation.png", 52, 50);
    sleepAnimation = new Animation(sleepSpriteSheet, 250);
    walkSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("res/images/characters/knight/spritesheets/WalkAnimation.png", 35, 48);
    walkAnimation = new Animation(walkSpriteSheet, 75);

}

// Get the ID of the GameState
@Override
public int getID() {
    return 0;
}

// MenuIntro thread
static class MenuIntro implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            readyForIntro = true;
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            readyForPlay = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the game level (Which is broken):

```
//Colors RGB
private static String Grey = "rgb/Grey.png";
private static String Blue = "rgb/Blue.png";
private static String Red = "rgb/Red.png";

// Level Variables
private static boolean stateStarted = false;
private static boolean startBossBattle = false;
private static boolean startedBossBattle = false;
private static boolean startedBossMusic = false;
private static boolean BothTouching = false;

// Player Variables
/* Coordinates, And Direction */
private static float PlayerX = 25;
private static float PlayerY = 470;
private static String Knight = "res/images/characters/knight/Knight.png";
private static String PlayerDirection = "right";
private static int PlayerHealth = 100;
private static boolean PlayerWalking = false;
private static boolean PlayerJumping = false;
private static boolean PlayerJumped = false;
private static float AmountPlayerJumped;
private static boolean PlayerAttacking = false;
private static boolean PlayerCanAttack = true;
private static int PlayerRegenTime = 100;
/* Sprite Sheets */
private static String PlayerLeftSword = "res/images/icons/sword/SwordLeft.png";
private static String PlayerLeftAttackSword = "res/images/icons/sword/SwordLeftAttacking.png";
private static String PlayerRightSword = "res/images/icons/sword/SwordRight.png";
private static String PlayerRightAttackSword = "res/images/icons/sword/SwordRightAttacking.png";
private static String PlayerCurrentSword = PlayerRightSword;
private static String RightKnight = "res/images/characters/knight/ResizedKnightRight.png";
private static String LeftKnight = "res/images/characters/knight/ResizedKnightLeft.png";
/* Everything Else */
private static boolean PlayerCanMove = false;

// AI Variables
/* Coordiantes and Direction */
private static float EnemyX = 1000;
private static float EnemyY = 470;
private static String EnemyKnight = "res/images/characters/knight/Knight.png";
private static String EnemyDirection = "right";
private static int EnemyHealth = 100;
private static boolean EnemyWalking = false;
private static boolean DecidedJump = false;
private static int JumpPossibility = 1;
private static boolean EnemyJumping = false;
private static boolean EnemyJumped = false;
private static float AmountEnemyJumped;
private static boolean EnemyAttacking = false;
private static boolean EnemyCanAttack = true;
private static int EnemyRegenTime = 100;
/* Sprite Sheets */
private static String EnemyLeftSword = "res/images/icons/sword/SwordLeft.png";
private static String EnemyLeftAttackSword = "res/images/icons/sword/SwordLeftAttacking.png";
private static String EnemyRightSword = "res/images/icons/sword/SwordRight.png";
private static String EnemyRightAttackSword = "/res/images/icons/sword/SwordRightAttacking.png";
private static String EnemyCurrentSword = EnemyRightSword;
private static String RightEnemy = "res/images/characters/knight/ResizedKnightRight.png";
private static String LeftEnemy = "res/images/characters/knight/ResizedKnightLeft.png";

/* Everything Else */
private static boolean EnemyTalking = false;
private static String EnemyMessage = "";
private static boolean EnemyCanMove = false;

// Mixed Variables
/* Sprite Sheets */
private static SpriteSheet WalkRightSpriteSheet;
private static Animation WalkRightAnimation;
private static SpriteSheet WalkLeftSprite;
private static Animation WalkLeftAnimation;
private static int SpriteSheetWidth = 135;
private static int SpriteSheetHeight = 188;



// System Variables
private String operatingSystem = Client.getOS();

// Constructor
public FinalBattle(int State) {
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer GameContainer, StateBasedGame SBG,
        Graphics G) throws SlickException {
    //GameContainer Things
    GameContainer.setShowFPS(false);

    //Level
    /* Draw Background */
    G.drawImage(new Image("res/images/level/FinalBattle.png"), 0, 0);

    /* Draw Floor */
    G.drawImage(new Image(Block.GroundTile), 0, 656);

    //Player
    /* Draw Player */
    if(PlayerWalking) {
        if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
            if(!PlayerJumping) {
                WalkRightAnimation.draw(PlayerX, PlayerY, SpriteSheetWidth, SpriteSheetHeight);
            }
            else {
                G.drawImage(new Image(RightKnight), PlayerX, PlayerY);
            }
            G.drawImage(new Image(PlayerCurrentSword), PlayerX + 60, PlayerY + 90);
        }
        if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
            if(!PlayerJumping) {
                WalkLeftAnimation.draw(PlayerX, PlayerY, SpriteSheetWidth, SpriteSheetHeight);
            }
            else {
                G.drawImage(new Image(LeftKnight), PlayerX, PlayerY);
            }
            G.drawImage(new Image(PlayerCurrentSword), PlayerX + 6, PlayerY + 90);
        }
    }

    /* Draw his/her sword */
    else {
        if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
            G.drawImage(new Image(RightKnight), PlayerX, PlayerY);
            G.drawImage(new Image(PlayerCurrentSword), PlayerX + 60, PlayerY + 90);
        }
        if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
            G.drawImage(new Image(LeftKnight), PlayerX, PlayerY);
            G.drawImage(new Image(PlayerCurrentSword), PlayerX + 6, PlayerY + 90);
        }
    }

    /* Draw his/her power level */
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.blue.darker()));
    G.drawString("Knight Power Level", 10, 20);
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.white));
    G.drawImage(new Image(Grey).getScaledCopy(100, 10), 10, 40);
    G.drawImage(new Image(Blue).getScaledCopy(PlayerRegenTime, 10), 10, 40);

    /* Draw his/her health level */
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.red.darker()));
    G.drawString("Knight Health", 10, 60);
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.white));
    G.drawImage(new Image(Grey).getScaledCopy(100, 10), 10, 80);
    G.drawImage(new Image(Red).getScaledCopy(PlayerHealth, 10), 10, 80);

    /* Draw his/her name */
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.red.darker()));
    G.drawString("You\n |\n\\ /", PlayerX + 50, PlayerY - 70);
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.white));


    //Enemy 
    if(EnemyWalking) {
        if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
            if(!EnemyJumping) {
                WalkRightAnimation.draw(EnemyX, EnemyY, SpriteSheetWidth, SpriteSheetHeight);
            }
            else {
                G.drawImage(new Image(RightKnight), EnemyX, EnemyY);
            }
            G.drawImage(new Image(EnemyCurrentSword), EnemyX + 60, EnemyY + 90);
        }
        if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
            if(!EnemyJumping) {
                WalkLeftAnimation.draw(EnemyX, EnemyY, SpriteSheetWidth, SpriteSheetHeight);
            }
            else {
                G.drawImage(new Image(LeftKnight), EnemyX, EnemyY);
            }
            G.drawImage(new Image(EnemyCurrentSword), EnemyX + 6, EnemyY + 90);
        }
    }

    /* Draw enemy sword */
    else {
        if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
            if(!EnemyAttacking) {
                EnemyCurrentSword = EnemyRightSword;
            }
            G.drawImage(new Image(RightKnight), EnemyX, EnemyY);
            G.drawImage(new Image(EnemyCurrentSword), EnemyX + 60, EnemyY + 90);
        }
        if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
            if(!EnemyAttacking) {
                EnemyCurrentSword = EnemyLeftSword;
            }
            G.drawImage(new Image(LeftKnight), EnemyX, EnemyY);
            G.drawImage(new Image(EnemyCurrentSword), EnemyX + 6, EnemyY + 90);
        }
    }

    /* Draw enemy power level */
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.blue.darker()));
    G.drawString("Enemy Power Level", 1115, 20);
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.white));
    G.drawImage(new Image(Grey).getScaledCopy(100, 10), 1165, 40);
    G.drawImage(new Image(Blue).getScaledCopy(EnemyRegenTime, 10), 1165, 40);

    /* Draw enemy health level */
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.red.darker()));
    G.drawString("Enemy Health", 1115, 60);
    G.setColor(new Color(Color.white));
    G.drawImage(new Image(Grey).getScaledCopy(100, 10), 1165, 80);
    G.drawImage(new Image(Red).getScaledCopy(EnemyHealth, 10), 1165, 80);

    // System Info (Not used currently)
    /*G.drawString("Game State: " + this.getID(), 10, 30);
    G.drawString("X:" + Mouse.getX() + " Y:" + Mouse.getY(), 10, 50);
    G.drawString("Your OS: " + operatingSystem, 10, 70);
    G.drawString("Player X: " + PlayerY + " Enemy X:" + EnemyX, 10, 170);*/
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer GameContainer, StateBasedGame SBG,
        int Delta) throws SlickException {

    // Fixes for some stuff that might happen
    if(PlayerY > 470) {
        PlayerY = 470;
    }
    if(EnemyY > 470) {
        EnemyY = 470;
    }

    // Enemy
    if(!EnemyTalking) {
        new Thread(new startFight()).start();
        EnemyTalking = true;
    }
    /* Boss Battle Music */
    if(startBossBattle && !startedBossBattle) {
        if(!startedBossMusic) {
            PlaySound.playSound("res/sounds/events/BossBattleLoop.wav");
            PlaySound.startLoop(1000);
            startedBossMusic = true;
        }
        startedBossBattle = true;
    }

    // Player
    /* Player Movement */
    if(PlayerCanMove) {
        Input playerInput = GameContainer.getInput();
        if(playerInput.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)) {
            PlayerX -= Delta*.3f;
            PlayerWalking = true;
            PlayerDirection = "left";
            if(!PlayerAttacking) {
                PlayerCurrentSword = PlayerLeftSword;
            }
        }
        else if(playerInput.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)) {
            PlayerX += Delta*.3f;
            PlayerWalking = true;
            PlayerDirection = "right";
            if(!PlayerAttacking) {
                PlayerCurrentSword = PlayerRightSword;
            }
        }
        else {
            PlayerWalking = false;
        }

        /* Player Jumping */
        if(playerInput.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_SPACE)) {
            if(!PlayerJumped) {
                new Thread(new playerJump()).start();
            }
        }
        if(PlayerJumping) {
            PlayerY -= Delta*.5f;
            AmountPlayerJumped = PlayerY;
        }
        else {
            if(PlayerY < 470) {
                PlayerY += Delta*.5f;
            }
            if(Math.round(PlayerY) == 470 || Math.round(PlayerY) == 471) {
                PlayerJumped = false;
            }
        }

        /* Player Attack */
        if(playerInput.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ENTER)) {
            if(PlayerCanAttack) {
                new Thread(new playerAttack()).start();
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }

    /* Player Collision Detection */
    if(PlayerX < 0) {
        PlayerX = 0;
    }
    if (PlayerX > 1155) {
        PlayerX = 1155;
    }

    //Enemy
    /* Enemy Movement and Jumping */
    if(EnemyCanMove) {
            if(PlayerX < EnemyX) {
                if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                    if(!(EnemyX - 125 < PlayerX)) {
                        EnemyX -= Delta*.2f;
                        EnemyDirection = "right";
                        EnemyWalking = true;
                        BothTouching = false;
                        if(!(EnemyX - 50 < PlayerX)) {
                            if(!DecidedJump) {
                                int Jump = GenerateNumber.generateNumber(JumpPossibility);
                                if(Jump == JumpPossibility) {
                                    new Thread(new enemyJump()).start();
                                }
                                DecidedJump = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            DecidedJump = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        EnemyWalking = false;
                        BothTouching = true;
                        if(EnemyRegenTime == 100) {
                            if(EnemyCanAttack) {
                                new Thread(new enemyAttack()).start();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                    if(!(EnemyX - 110 < PlayerX)) {
                        EnemyX -= Delta*.2f;
                        EnemyDirection = "left";
                        EnemyWalking = true;
                        BothTouching = false;
                        if(!(EnemyX + 50 < PlayerX)) {
                            if(!DecidedJump) {
                                int Jump = GenerateNumber.generateNumber(JumpPossibility);
                                if(Jump == JumpPossibility) {
                                    new Thread(new enemyJump()).start();
                                }
                                DecidedJump = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            DecidedJump = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        EnemyWalking = false;
                        BothTouching = true;
                        if(EnemyRegenTime == 100) {
                            if(EnemyRegenTime == 100) {
                                if(EnemyCanAttack) {
                                    new Thread(new enemyAttack()).start();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                EnemyDirection = "left";
            }
            if(PlayerX > EnemyX) {
                if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                    if(!(EnemyX + 119 > PlayerX)) {
                        EnemyX += Delta*.2f;
                        EnemyDirection = "right";
                        EnemyWalking = true;
                        BothTouching = false;
                        if(!(EnemyX - 50 < PlayerX)) {
                            if(!DecidedJump) {
                                int Jump = GenerateNumber.generateNumber(JumpPossibility);
                                if(Jump == JumpPossibility) {
                                    new Thread(new enemyJump()).start();
                                }
                                DecidedJump = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            DecidedJump = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        EnemyWalking = false;
                        BothTouching = true;
                        if(EnemyRegenTime == 100) {
                            if(EnemyRegenTime == 100) {
                                if(EnemyCanAttack) {
                                    new Thread(new enemyAttack()).start();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                    if(!(EnemyX + 135 > PlayerX)) {
                        EnemyX += Delta*.2f;
                        EnemyDirection = "left";
                        EnemyWalking = true;
                        BothTouching = false;
                        if(!(EnemyX + 50 < PlayerX)) {
                            if(!DecidedJump) {
                                int Jump = GenerateNumber.generateNumber(JumpPossibility);
                                if(Jump == JumpPossibility) {
                                    new Thread(new enemyJump()).start();
                                }
                                DecidedJump = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            DecidedJump = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        EnemyWalking = false;
                        BothTouching = true;
                        if(EnemyRegenTime == 100) {
                            if(EnemyRegenTime == 100) {
                                if(EnemyCanAttack) {
                                    new Thread(new enemyAttack()).start();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                EnemyDirection = "right";
            }
            /* Enemy Jumping */
            if(EnemyJumping) {
                EnemyY -= Delta*.5f;
                AmountEnemyJumped = EnemyY;
            }
            else {
                if(EnemyY < 470) {
                    EnemyY += Delta*.5f;
                }
                if(Math.round(EnemyY) == 470 || Math.round(EnemyY) == 471) {
                    EnemyJumped = false;
                }
            }
    }

}

// Initializing Constructor
@Override
public void init(GameContainer GameContainer, StateBasedGame SBG)
        throws SlickException {
    WalkRightSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("res/images/characters/knight/spritesheets/WalkAnimationRight.png", 35, 48);
    WalkRightAnimation = new Animation(WalkRightSpriteSheet, 100);
    WalkLeftSprite = new SpriteSheet("res/images/characters/knight/spritesheets/WalkAnimationLeft.png", 35, 48);
    WalkLeftAnimation = new Animation(WalkLeftSprite, 100);
}

// Gets the ID of the current State
@Override
public int getID() {
    return 1;
}

// Start Fight
static class startFight implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            startBossBattle = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

// Player Threads
/* Player Attack */
static class playerAttack implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            PlayerAttacking = true;
            if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                PlayerCurrentSword = PlayerRightAttackSword;
            }
            if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                PlayerCurrentSword = PlayerLeftAttackSword;
            }
            if(BothTouching) {
                EnemyHealth -= 10;
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                PlayerCurrentSword = PlayerRightSword;
            }
            if(PlayerDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                PlayerCurrentSword = PlayerLeftSword;
            }
            PlayerAttacking = false;
            PlayerCanAttack = false;
            PlayerRegenTime = 0;
            while(PlayerRegenTime != 100) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                PlayerRegenTime++;
            }
            PlayerCanAttack = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}

/* Player Jump */
static class playerJump implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            PlayerJumped = true;
            PlayerJumping = true;
            Thread.sleep(750);
            PlayerJumping = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

// Enemy Threads
/* Enemy Attack */
static class enemyAttack implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
                EnemyAttacking = true;
                if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                    EnemyCurrentSword = EnemyRightAttackSword;
                }
                if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                    EnemyCurrentSword = EnemyLeftAttackSword;
                }
                PlayerHealth -= 10;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
                    EnemyCurrentSword = EnemyRightSword;
                }
                if(EnemyDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
                    EnemyCurrentSword = EnemyLeftSword;
                }
                EnemyAttacking = false;
                EnemyCanAttack = false;
                EnemyRegenTime = 0;
                while(EnemyRegenTime != 100) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    EnemyRegenTime++;
                }
                EnemyCanAttack = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

/* Decide Jump */
static class decideJump implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
            int number = GenerateNumber.generateNumber(20);
            if(number == 20) {
                if(!EnemyJumping) {
                    new Thread(new enemyJump()).start();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

/* Enemy Jump */
static class enemyJump implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            EnemyJumped = true;
            EnemyJumping = true;
            Thread.sleep(750);
            EnemyJumping = false;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Yes I do, Here it is. http://pastebin.com/Lnz6pPzR Also, Just so you know, the image does show!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that I wasnt adding it to the build path. If you are viewing this with this problem, make sure to add it to your build path in Eclipse (Or netbeans).